# How do I open URLs in my tabbed webbrowser instead of Internet Explorer?

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, browser, tabs, basic

I have made a tabbed web browser in my visual basic application which uses a tabcontrol. I want my browser to open any links in a new tab in my tabcontrol instead of internet explorer what should I do?

I would prefer not to change the code, simply add code.

Here's the code for my `form1_load` event:

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Browser As New WebBrowser
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add("New Page")
    Browser.Name = "Web Browser"
    Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browser)
    AddHandler Browser.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Loading
    AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Done
    int = int + 1
    CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(My.Settings.homepage)
    Browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
End Sub
```

add tab code:

```
Public Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    Dim Browser As New WebBrowser
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add("New Page")
    TabControl1.SelectTab(int)
    Browser.Name = "Web Browser"
    Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browser)
    AddHandler Browser.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Loading
    AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Done
    int = int + 1
    CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(My.Settings.homepage)
    Browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
End Sub
```

Comment: **"open any links in a new tab in my tabcontrol instead of internet explorer what should I do"** do not use the WebBrowser control... it is derived from Internet Explorer... Your code needs changed as well.

Comment: then please tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Add handlers on each html link element

```
Private Sub Done(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    'Throw New NotImplementedException

    For Each element As HtmlElement In sender.Document.Links
        AddHandler element.Click, AddressOf OpenNewTab
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub OpenNewTab(sender As Object, e As HtmlElementEventArgs)
    'Your existing code to instantiate a new tab
End Sub
```

Comment: Where to add that each html elements? In the form load?

Comment: in the Navigated event of the webbrowser instance

Comment: yes obviously, that is why I said its the webbrowser instance Navigated event. I've added a new code snippet in my answer. maybe you want to  try it in the form load first before moving it to the Navigated event

Comment: i am a little bit confused please tell me in your answer how will the code look at the end. copy the form1 load code from the question and then post it with the edits then add the complete codes in your answer so i can see how will the code look at the end because i keep getting some errors when putting the code

Comment: my apologies, please disregard the previous snippets, I've made corrections on the code

Comment: Well After You Corrected The Code, A New Tab Is Opened When I Click On Any Link That Requires a New Tab But The New Tab Just Navigates To The Home page (as the tab is requested to navigate to homepage when it is added) so i still need a code to make the new tab navigate to the URL that should have opened, another thing that even if the new tab opens when i click the link internet explorer still opens so i want a code to stop internet explorer from opening.

So in total, i need a code to make the new tab navigate to the URL i clicked and a code to stop internet explorer from opening.

Comment: Where Are You?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: i have waiting for your reply for days ?!

Comment: dude, why aren't you answering me ?!

Comment: take a hint. i don't have any answers as to why your links open up strangely in IE. if you feel that my code snippet didn't help you in any way, feel free to down vote it.